# nodejs api returning nothing

Tags: node.js, angularjs, api, mean-stack

I am trying to implement MEAN app for which I made node server

```
app.get("/posts",(req,res)=>{
posts=[{"title":"a","context":"b"},{"title":"c","context":"d"}] 
res.send(posts); // tried even with res.status(200).json(posts)   
});
```

when it checked with api tester it works well output snapshot
[output snapshot with apitester](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Epcb.png)

when i try to access with angular services

```
getposts()
      {
        var url='http://localhost:3000/posts';
        this.http.get<post[]>(url).subscribe(data=>this.posts=data);   
        console.log(this.posts);
        return this.posts;

      }
```

when i do console.log(posts) it returning []

can someone please help i am struggling from last 2 days?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: no can u please write answer for  this question

Answer (score -1):

As you have not added the screenshot from the Browser's Inspector => Network Tab, I am guessing this answer will help you in case my guess is right.

Try setting the below in your *front-end* project (Angular in your case):

[image: Request Headers]

Try setting the below in your *back-end* project (Node in your case):

[image: Response Headers]

Also, **verify** your updates as in the below screengrab in the Browser's Inspector (*Chrome* in my case):

[image: Chrome's Inspector Screenshot]

*Please Note*: - The mentioned *response headers* have special meaning, so kindly look for more info with a simple Google search. Use these settings during your *development* phase on *localhost*.

Comment: For whoever has down voted this answer, I respect their view, but may I also know the reason please? I have given my time and effort to guess the actual issue and to answer it provided that, the same was mentioned in the answer itself that the question is not fully complete.